# ValueError: cross_val_predict only works for partitions

Tags: python, precision, cross-validation

I have a multi-class classification problem with feature array (X) and the dependent variable array (y). y has four classes: 1, 2, 3 and 4. There is a severe imbalance in data, there is only a handful of observations for class 4. I have chosen the classifier model as:

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, class_weight='balanced', random_state=0)
```

I have defined a custom scorer as:

```
custom_scorer = {'accuracy': make_scorer(accuracy_score),
                 'balanced_accuracy': make_scorer(balanced_accuracy_score),
                 'precision': make_scorer(precision_score, average='weighted'),
                 'recall': make_scorer(recall_score, average='weighted'),
                 'roc auc': make_scorer(roc_auc_score, multi_class='ovo', needs_proba=True),
                 'f1': make_scorer(f1_score, average='weighted')
                 }
```

Due to data imbalance, I am using cross_validate:

```
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
scores = cross_validate(model, X, y, cv=cv, scoring=custom_scorer, n_jobs=-1)
```

From the `scores` I am getting the metrics accuracy, balanced_accuracy, precision, recall etc. However, this gives me only the metrics, not the array containing predicted class. I want to get `y_pred` (predicted values of y) as well that might have been generated internally while executing the following line of code:

```
scores = cross_validate(model, X, y, cv=cv, scoring=custom_scorer, n_jobs=-1)
```

However, to get the prediction of y, I am using:

```
y_pred = cross_val_predict(model, X, y, cv=cv)
```

This gives me an error:

**ValueError: cross_val_predict only works for partitions**

If I change the above code to

```
y_pred = cross_val_predict(model, X, y, cv=10)
```

then I can avoid the error, but cv=cv and cv=10 are not the same things, are they? If I calculate precision, recall etc. corresponding to each class by using:

```
precision, recall, fscore, support = score(y, y_pred)
```

those cannot correspond to the *scores* I calculated using *cross_validate*.

I also need the probability values calculated for y.

```
y_proba = cross_val_predict(model, X, y, cv=cv, method='predict_proba')
```

This also gives me an error

**ValueError: cross_val_predict only works for partitions**

Please help.